# Orthogonality Relations for $\sin kx$ and $\cos nx$ for arbitrary domains

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, orthogonality

Here are a summary of the orthogonality relations for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$

[image]

What happens if we change the interval of integration to say $[0, \pi]$ or $[0, 1]$ or most generally $[a, b]$? Do the above orthogonality relations still hold for $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Comment: Try some of the examples you suggest---the answer will become apparent quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly not.

For example,
if you choose an interval,
such as $[0, .01]$,
over which
all the functions
(for some $k$ and $n$)
have the same sign,
then the integral
of their product
can never be zero.

More generally,
use the formulas for
$\sin(x)\sin(y)$
and similarly
to get the indefinite integrals.
You will see why
$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$
is special.